# Different header heights on different pages

Tags: margins, fancyhdr

I'm writing solutions for math contest and I have some troubles with margins. In one file I want to have more than one solution, but every solution should start on a new page. The first page of each solution has longer header (9 lines on the left), while other pages have shorter headers (2 lines on the left), but on every page I should also put problem number in the header (on the right, with increased font and in bold). There should be also page numbering in the footer.

I've managed to solve almost everything, but I have some troubles with bottom margin - it's different on the first page of each solution, but I want it to be the same on all pages. What should I do?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\usepackage[top=2cm, right=2cm,left=2cm, textheight=23cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\voffset}{0.7cm}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}



\fancypagestyle{full}{%
\setlength{\headheight}{9\baselineskip}%
\setlength{\headsep}{0.6cm}%
\fancyhead[L]{%
Some text\hfill {\fontsize{16}{10}\selectfont \hfill \textbf{Problem \theprob}}\\%
Some text\\
Some text\\
some text\\
some text\\
some  longer text some longer text\\
some text\\
some text\\
some text
\smallskip
\hrule%
}%
\rfoot{\thepage}
}


\fancypagestyle{short}{%
\setlength{\headheight}{2\baselineskip}
\setlength{\headsep}{0.6cm}%
\fancyhead[L]{%
Some text\hfill {\fontsize{16}{10}\selectfont \hfill \textbf{Problem \theprob}}\\%
some text
\smallskip
\hrule
}%
\rfoot{\thepage}
}


\newcounter{prob}% <-- current problem number
\setcounter{prob}{0}

\newcommand{\problem}{%
\newpage%
\addtocounter{prob}{1}%
\thispagestyle{full}%
\pagestyle{short}%
}





\begin{document}
\problem
\lipsum \lipsum \lipsum


\problem
\lipsum \lipsum \lipsum


\end{document}
```

If I remove any of the packages I use (apart from `lipsum`), formatting changes (I have no idea why `mathpazo` and `mathtools` influence the formatting, but they do make some difference).

Also why do warnings on too small headers pop out? This is probably not of great importance here, but I though that `2\baselineskip` is enough for 2 lines of text.

Comment: Just a question: do you think it is sensible to have a 16pt font size in a header?

Comment: @Bernard It's not the final output, I just wanted to highlight that the font may be bigger here in case font size affects some other parts of code.

Comment: This is probably  a consequence of your varying header height. You can't change the geometry of the page on each page so easily. How can 9 \baselineskips fit in a top of 2cm anyway?

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do - change page geometry many times. If allthe headers had the same height, I probably wouldn't have any problem.